# Java List generics syntax for primitive types

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

I want to make a growable array of bytes. I.e a list.
In c# would usally do the following syntax

```
List<byte> mylist = new List<byte>();
```

where as in java this syntax does not work and I have googled around and found the below code

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

but that is not what I want. Any idea's where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the wrapper class `Byte`:

```
List<Byte> mylist = new ArrayList<Byte>();
```

Then, because of autoboxing, you can still have:

```
for (byte b : mylist) {

}
```

Comment: List is an interface, so you can't new one up. You'd need to use a concrete class instead, such as ArrayList or LinkedList

Comment: @Michael Williamson a typo, rather than me not knowing that ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that compared to an array of primitives, this kind of solution uses 5-9 times more memory and adds an additional layer of indirection for every access. AND allocates new memory every time a value in the List is changed.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use [TByteArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TByteArrayList.html) from the [GNU Trove library](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

You have a [`Byte`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) class provided by the JRE.

This class is the corresponding class for the `byte` primitive type.

See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for primitive types.

You can do this :

```
List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
byte b = 127;
myList.add(b);
b = 0; // resetting
b = myList.get(0); // => b = 127 again
```

As Michael pointed in the comments :

```
List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
Byte b = null;
myList.add(b);
byte primitiveByte = myList.get(0);
```

results in :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestPrimitive.main(TestPrimitive.java:12)
```

Comment: It's probably worth adding that generics and primitives don't play nicely together -- that is, you can't use a primitive as a type argument, hence the need to use Byte instead of byte. Autoboxing isn't perfect -- a Byte can be null, where as a byte can't, so trying to assign a Byte to a byte can result in a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Bozho: They still show up as the first results on Google or Bing. One nice example where search engines suck ;-)

Comment: I always edit the URL (`j2se/1.4.2` => `javase/6`) before posting links to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using an `ArrayList<Byte>` to store a growable array of bytes is probably not a good idea, since each byte gets boxed, which means a new Byte object is allocated. So the total memory cost per byte is one pointer in the ArrayList + one Byte object.

It's probably better to use a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. There, the memory cost per byte is 1 byte.

We can provide better advice if you describe the context a little more.