# Java equivalent to C++ std::vector?

Tags: java, c++, arraylist

Until today i thought ArrayLists in Java and C++ std::vectors where the same, but turns out ArrayLists can only store objects. (Primitives are wrapped). What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
class Array {

    int i;
    type[] array;

    Array() {
        this.i = 0;
        this.array = new array[1];
    }

    Array(int initialSize) {
         this.i = 0;
         this.array = new array[initialSize];
    }

    type get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    void add(type to_add) {
        if(array.length == i) {
            type[] newArray = new type[array.length * 2];
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) newArray[j] = array[j]; 
        }
        array[i++] = to_add; 
    }

}
```

"type" is one of the primitive datatypes.

Note: I do not need the ability to store objects, so I don't want the memory overhead of an ArrayList.

If any of my assumptions are wrong, please let me know :-D

Edit:
This is not a duplicate, this is a question about performance, not on whether it is possible.

Comment: If it's only about not **wanting**, I'd say don't be ridiculous. If you actually have an important performance issue (which I doubt, because you wouldn't be asking something like this) look into 3rd party libraries that offer you primitive collections.

Comment: In contrast to `C++` Java is *really* an object oriented programming language. So if you want to code with Java just get used to objects...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java List generics syntax for primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302003/java-list-generics-syntax-for-primitive-types)

Comment: *Note: I do not need the ability to store objects, so I don't want the memory overhead of an ArrayList* -- C++ is not Java and Java is not C++.  Just because they look similar doesn't mean you can write code using C++ as a model in writing Java code, and vice-versa.  All that will end up doing is writing code that is usually inefficient, wrong, and just plain silly and weird-looking in the language you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. @Kayaman I studdy both languages at uni and had a miss-understanding about how ArrayLists worked.  If there is no propper way to do it in Java, that's good to know. But is there something inherently wrong with the code above if you replace the type with one of the primitive datatypes?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is the what I propose here inefficient? I'm studding at university, I'm asking about the performance of an ArrayList because I want to learn about it, sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: @H.Boe -- First, this question is tagged `C++`, so get the perspective from someone who uses it every day.  If you look at the answer you accepted, note that the library that is linked is *algorithmically* more efficient (or claims to be) than `ArrayList`.  My main point is that you cannot compare a language that can work with the "bare metal" such as C++, and a language that works by utilizing a VM, like Java.  Compare C++ compilers with other C++ compilers, compare a JVM implementation to another JVM.  Don't cross C++ with Java, as it makes very little sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard (Java SE) libraries do not provide an equivalent of the C++ `std::vector` clss that works with Java primitive types.  The alternatives are:

- Use standard classes like `ArrayList` with (say) `Integer` as the type parameter.
- Use a 3rd-party library.  For example, the old GNU Trove library.  (NB: this is not a recommendation.  It is an example.)

Trove and similar are not and cannot be implemented using Java generics.  This is because Java only allows reference types to be used as parameters for generic classes.  So these Java libraries are actually implemented as "copy and paste" code with collection APIs that are not polymorphic to any great extent.

Comment: Despite you mark the mention of Trove as not a recommendation, effectively such mention still works as a recommendation. Please mention fastutil or Eclipse Collections instead of Trove, at least those libraries are supported.

Comment: If you wish to write your own answer giving your own recommendations, please feel free to do so.  If people choose to willfully misinterpret my clear "this is not a recommendation" ... that is their problem.